# What thread handles modal dialog windows in .Net?

Tags: .net, multithreading, modal-dialog

I have a pretty basic understanding of the GUI thread and the message loop, but I'm curious as to how that applies to one window starting a modal window. If I had to guess, I'd say that both windows are being run under the same GUI thread and that some parameter indicates that only events with the child window (the modal one) be executed, otherwise point out the modal window to the user.

This is simply a semi-educated guess and I accept that I may be wrong from square one. I'm not even sure if "GUI thread" is the right name for that thread, but people usually can guess what I'm talking about.

So in short, how do threads and modal windows get along together?

Comment: Opening a modal dialog is a blocking call. The calling window waits for the modal dialog to close before processing any more events itself.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, so is the modal window running in a new thread while the parent window is blocked? What exactly does that imply for the parent window's events such as repainting?

Comment: My understanding is that the modal dialog still runs on the main GUI thread. If you want processing to occur in the background (including repainting of the main form) while a modal dialog is being displayed, you have to spin off a new thread for the background process to run in.

Comment: The parent window is still repainted, so some events are still being executed on the parent window. What if I invoke a method on the main window from a second thread while the parent window is displaying a modal window? Will the GUI thread run the invoke? Or because of the block is an error thrown in the other thread?

Comment: +1 interesting and intriguing question. The answer: no threads, message loops ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This maybe contradictory, but no, no new thread is started for the new windows. However, a new message loop is opened. This keeps messages flowing through Windows and avoids halting other applications.

Messages will arrive and may be dispatched to the owner window's message loop. On the owner window, keyboard and mouse input have been disabled, but all other messages will be send through. *Note from Hans Passant: actually, all top level windows of the same thread will be disabled this way.*

As an example that you already touch on in your question, `WM_PAINT` is send through to the parent window. But also `WM_TIMER`, for instance. A message like `WM_NCHITTEST` will not be send through, as it is an input message. Nor will `WM_KEYDOWN` and similar.

This way, a messagebox can be moved, and the underlying owner gets neatly repainted, or a ticking clock still continues ticking.

*Information partially from [Rector and Newcomer's Win32 Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634929), page 752+, old, but still valuable and valid info. This info applies to `DialogBox`, `DialogBoxParam`, `DialogBoxIndirect` and `DialogBoxIndirectParam` as well as any of the `..Ex` versions. Internally, these Win32 API functions are called by WinForms.*

Comment: 'old' - but these parts of Windows are even older

Comment: @Tim, that's correct :) I tried to find its origin, but it seems that the [oldest reference Microsoft uses is Windows 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645452.aspx), no function, not even [`WinMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559.aspx), goes further back.

Comment: @Abel, that's a nice bit of history rewriting :). Presumably those versions numbers in MSDN are _min(Windows version supported by Microsoft, first Windows version function appeared in)_. I should check my Windows 3.0 edition of Petzold.

Comment: @Tim: haha, I wasn't serious, I just meant that Microsoft stopped keeping track of older Windows versions (probably part of their end-of-support program).

Comment: +1, this is accurate.  Might want to mention that it also iterates the top-level windows owned by the same thread and disables them.

Comment: @Hans P: thanks, I added your note to the solution. There are, actually, more subtleties involved when dealing with modal dialog boxes, that all in all require a chapter in a book ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Both windows remain on the same thread. That thread -- the GUI thread -- continues to process messages for both windows.

What's special about a modal dialog is:

- The dialog's owner is set to the main window. This causes the dialog to always appear on top of the main window. [It's possible to do this with modeless windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484547/what-sort-of-form-window-is-the-excel-2010-searchandreplace-dialog)
- The owner window stops receiving user input (mouse and keyboard messages) while the dialog is open. The dialog receives user input as normal. This is achieved by disabling the owner window, in the same way that you might disable a control on a dialog box.

Comment: Note: it is possible, of course, to set the owner to another window, for instance (which is often done wrong by junior programmers), the desktop.

Comment: Random side question, is there an advantage to setting a window's owner to the desktop? I've never heard of this being done.

Comment: There is no advantage. The disadvantage is that it breaks Windows.

Comment: *"I've never heard of this being done"* >> many free, cheap or shareware programs, or programs ported from Java or other to Windows have this problem, which can be noted when the input focus is removed, but the dialog box is not visible, unless you minimize all windows, where one window will remain on top. As Tim says: no advantage at all. Note that this blocking behavior has changed in Vista and changed further in Windows 7. An example is the Apache Monitor tool, when Apache doesn't start as the result of an error. The dialog box owner is the desktop and the window is hidden behind the owner.

Comment: Sounds like a good thing I don't run into this in my own applications.

Answer (score 0):

A window, or rather a window's messages, are handled by the thread that created the window: called [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx). This might be indirect, with layers of software between the application code and the `CreateWindowEx` API call, but the call will always be there when creating a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Modal Dialog Boxes
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994(v=vs.85).aspx

*To process messages for the modal dialog box, the system starts its own message loop, taking temporary control of the message queue for the entire application. When the system retrieves a message that is not explicitly for the dialog box, it dispatches the message to the appropriate window. If it retrieves a `WM_QUIT` message, it posts the message back to the application message queue so that the application's main message loop can eventually retrieve the message.*