# Showing a modal dialog (messageBox) freezes other windows in the application

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I have an application that shows multiple different top-level windows hosted in the same message-loop thread.  This exists to allow the user to open up different views of the same data.  (In MS Outlook, you can right-click on another folder and select "open in a new window" to get similar behavior).

The problem that I have is that when one of these windows opens up a modal dialog or messagebox it freezes all of the sibling windows of the parent.

When I open a modal dialog I would like it to only be modal relative to the parent/owner window and not modal with respect to the other top-level windows in the application.  Is there any reasonable way to do this?  I have considered:

- Replacing modal dialogs with non-modal dialogs and disabling the parent window when they open
- Creating different threads within the application for each of these windows

Any advice?

Comment: There is no good solution to this, AFAIK.  I'd love to hear of one.

Comment: I think your best bet is to go with ("Replacing modal dialogs with non-modal dialogs and disabling the parent window when they open") and then Disabling the ParentForm and then subscribe all forms to an event that if the form closes it checks if there are any other open forms (some sort of counter maybe?) and then if there are none enabling the main form again

Comment: there is quite a lot of discussion  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494539/what-thread-handles-modal-dialog-windows-in-net

Answer (score 4):

This is what 'modal' means.  You have to make it non-modal, use a form and display it with its Show() method.  To disable parts of the UI, set the Enabled property of the controls or forms to false.  Use the form's FormClosed event to set it back to true.  Beware that this doesn't typically improve usability.